# A reference for a simple lemma on positive solutions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Where one may find any reference to lemmas the following kind:

If $x(t)$ is $C_1$ in $[0,T], x(0)\gt0, \frac{dx}{dt} + c(t)x(t)\gt 0$ in $[0,T]$ then $x(t)\gt 0$ in $[0,T]$.

There is a version with weak inequalities.

This lemma is also provable for bounded variation functions (BV), if one imposes a restriction that the jumps must be positive.

I need to quote lemmas of this type. I will be grateful if you could provide me with appropriate references, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Proof: As a matter of fact, we have a stronger result than positivity.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + c(t)x(t)=e^{-\int_0^t c}\frac{d}{dt}\big(e^{\int_0^t c}x(t)\big)>0,$$
or equivalently 
$$e^{\int_0^t c}x(t)-x(0)>0,$$
or
$$x(t)>x(0)e^{-\int_0^t c}.$$
So, $x(0)>0\Longrightarrow x(t)>0.$

QED

Comment: ... and the reference is to Gronwall's inequality: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality which lists the source as Gronwall, Thomas H. (1919), "Note on the derivatives with respect to a parameter of the solutions of a system of differential equations", Ann. of Math. 20 (2): 292–296